# Haskell Exercise deconstructing record syntax

Tags: haskell, record

Starting Exercise to brush up on learned Haskell skills.

```
module Clock (addDelta, fromHourMin, clockDecons) where

data Clock = Clock { hours :: Int 
                   , mins  :: Int 
                   } deriving Show 

fromHourMin :: Int -> Int -> Clock
fromHourMin hour min = Clock {hours = hour, mins = min}

-- toString :: Clock -> String
clockDecons clock = (hs,ms) 
  where hs = hours 
        ms = mins

addDelta :: Int -> Int -> Clock -> Clock
addDelta hour min clock = undefined
```

Maybe a bit clouded after a complete day, but why do I get:

```
<interactive>:15:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (Clock -> Int))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I haven't even begun to create string instances of the clock.

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you call `print`, as indicated by the error message. I suspect, though, that you are trying something like `print hours x` instead of `print (hours x)`, since `hours` (and `mins`, for that matter) is a function of type `Clock -> Int`.

Comment: Your definition of `clockDecons` should probably also be applying `hours` and `mins` to `clock`. It also has the problem that `(hs, ms)` is a tuple, not a `String`.

Comment: Please include the code that generates the error. You can help us help you by reducing the amount of guesswork we have to make.

Comment: @chepner, Michael: posted the entire piece of code now. Not calling show or print anywhere (yet) so I really don't get it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: correct. Tried `clockDecons Clock {hours=22,mins=10}` and that triggers the error. But it should not considering I am asking `Int` in return. In a tuple, yes, but still an `Int`

Comment: Is that simply because I want to have something shown in GHCi? As a beginner I like GHCi just for verifying that it all works and of course for studying Haskell. In this case by the way it is `stack ghci src/Clock.hs`

Tips & Trics are welcome as always ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably meant

```
clockDecons :: Clock -> (Int, Int)
clockDecons clock = (hours clock, mins clock)
```

Comment: it is what I wanted, not what I meant, but it works and I can take it from there. Just shows me there's still a lot to learn. Anyway: got my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative:

```
clockDecons :: Clock -> (Int, Int)
clockDecons (Clock hs ms) = (hs, ms)
```

Alternative:

```
clockDecons :: Clock -> (Int, Int)
clockDecons Clock{hours=hs, mins=ms} = (hs, ms)
```

Alternative: don't use any `clockDecons` at all. You are essentially unwrapping two integers under the `Clock` constructor to rewrap them under the `(,)` constructor of pairs. This is not a `decons`. Keep the clock value wrapped until you actually need to deconstruct it.